# Suppose two metrics induce the same bornology; do they necessarily induce the same topological space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Every metric space $(X,d)$ gives rise to a [bornology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bornological+set) by asserting that $A \subseteq X$ is *bounded* iff there is an open ball (of finite radius) that includes $A$.

Now just because two metrics induce the same topological space, nonetheless they needn't induce the same bornology. E.g. Let $d$ denote the usual metric on $\mathbb{R},$ and take $d'(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y),1\}.$ Then $d'$ induces the same topology as $d$, but every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded with respect to $d'$.

**Question.** Suppose two metrics induce the same bornology. Do they necessarily induce the same topological space?

Comment: Is a bornology the same as [uniform space](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the usual metric on $[0,1]$ every subset is bounded. Under the discrete metric every subset is bounded, too.